Why there is segment fault when compile with clang15
Given the following code, built on x86 clang, and run, it will segment fault.
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/auxv.h>
// Provide default macro definitions in case that they are not defined on current linux distro.
// For example, TiFlash compiled on older linux kernels may also be used in newer ones.
// These values should be stable for Linux: only false negative is expected when running on
// older kernels, but it is acceptable as `google/cpu_features` is also doing so.
#ifndef HWCAP2_MTE
#define HWCAP2_MTE (1 << 18)
#endif
#ifndef HWCAP_SVE
#define HWCAP_SVE (1 << 22)
#endif
#ifndef AT_HWCAP2
#define AT_HWCAP2 26
#endif
#ifndef AT_HWCAP
#define AT_HWCAP 16
#endif
/// check if MTE is supported in current environment
static inline bool mte_supported(void)
{
    return (getauxval(AT_HWCAP2) & HWCAP2_MTE) != 0;
}
/// check if SVE is supported in current environment
static inline bool sve_supported(void)
{
    return (getauxval(AT_HWCAP) & HWCAP_SVE) != 0;
}
#define STRINGIFY_IMPL(X) #X
#define STRINGIFY(X) STRINGIFY_IMPL(X)
/**
 *  \brief
 *  Symbol is defined as hidden visibility. Therefore, implementations here are only to override routines with TiFlash
 *  binary itself. This is because dependencies like `ld.so`, `libgcc_s.so`, etc will need essential routines like
 *  `memcpy` to finish the early loading procedure. Therefore, declare such symbols as visible indirect function will
 *  create cyclic dependency. It shall be good enough to override symbols within TiFlash, as most heavy computation works
 *  are happening in the main binary.
 *  \param NAME: exported symbol name
 *  \param SVE: preferred implementation when SVE is available
 *  \param MTE: preferred implementation when MTE is available
 *  \param ASIMD: preferred implementation for generic aarch64 targets (ASIMD is required by default for Armv8 and above)
 */
#define DISPATCH(NAME, SVE, MTE, ASIMD)                                                                                  \
    extern typeof(ASIMD) __tiflash_##NAME __attribute__((ifunc(STRINGIFY(__tiflash_##NAME##_resolver))));                \
    extern typeof(ASIMD) NAME __attribute__((visibility("hidden"), alias(STRINGIFY(__tiflash_##NAME))));                 \
    _Pragma("GCC diagnostic push")                                                                                       \
        _Pragma("GCC diagnostic ignored \"-Wunused-function\"") static typeof(ASIMD) * __tiflash_##NAME##_resolver(void) \
    {                                                                                                                    \
        if (sve_supported())                                                                                             \
        {                                                                                                                \
            return SVE;                                                                                                  \
        }                                                                                                                \
        if (mte_supported())                                                                                             \
        {                                                                                                                \
            return MTE;                                                                                                  \
        }                                                                                                                \
        return ASIMD;                                                                                                    \
    }                                                                                                                    \
    _Pragma("GCC diagnostic pop")
#undef memcpy
DISPATCH(memcpy, memcpy, memcpy, memcpy)
int main() {
    char source[] = "once upon a daydream...", dest[4];
        memcpy(dest, source, sizeof dest);
    return 0;
}

The example on godbolt is https://godbolt.org/z/h1PWo9PoW.
I actually have already done some research:

clang 13 and gcc will not segfault
clang 15/17 will segfault
no segfault if run with LD_BIND_NOW=1
removing the two lines start with extern typeof(ASIMD), the program can compile, so the problem must relate to ifunc

By stepping, I found the problem is related to the PLT mechanism.
I have tried to compile the code by different compilers. The symbol of getauxval is resolved by PLT only in clang 15/17, this means the getauxval will actually call getauxval@plt instead. In gcc or clang13, there is no getauxval@plt, so the segfault won't happen.
getauxval@plt looks like the following when compiled with clang15
Dump of assembler code for function getauxval@plt:
=> 0x0000555555555930 <+0>: jmp    *0x2232(%rip)        # 0x555555557b68
   0x0000555555555936 <+6>: push   $0x1
   0x000055555555593b <+11>:    jmp    0x555555555910

IMO, the first time getauxval@plt is called, *0x2232(%rip) will point to push $0x1 so as to eventually call _dl_runtime_resolve. The second time getauxval@plt is called, *0x2232(%rip) will point directly to the real code of getauxval, which has been computed by _dl_runtime_resolve.
To summarize, if I run print /x *0x555555557b68 here, I will either get 0x0000555555555936 or some address that disass-ed to be the real code of getauxval.
However, when I step in and run print /x *0x555555557b68 here, it prints out
(gdb) p /x *0x555555557b68
$1 = 0x1936

The 0x1936 is completely nonsense here, it is neither the real code of getauxval nor 0x0000555555555936.
Here comes my question:

Where is the 0x1936 comes from? I believe it relates to ifunc or even something that relates to loading order of dynamic libs. However, I found it hard to locate the root cause.
How can I fix my code? This is because the LD_BIND_NOW=1 won't work on arm.

=== EDIT ===
Updated according to https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html.
I expect that code prints aaaaa, however, it doesn't.
#include <stdio.h>

void *my_memcpy (void *dst, const void *src, size_t len)
{
    printf("aaaaa\n");
    return dst;
}

static void * (*resolve_memcpy (void))(void *, const void *, size_t)
{
    return my_memcpy;
}

void *memcpy (void *, const void *, size_t) __attribute__ ((ifunc ("resolve_memcpy")));

extern void *memcpy (void *, const void *, size_t);

int main() {
    char source[] = "once upon a daydream...", dest[4];
    memcpy(dest, source, sizeof dest);
    return 0;
}

==== EDIT2 ====
Can I remove the #define memcpy memcpy2 here?
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static int use_embed = 1;

void *my_memcpy (void *dst, const void *src, size_t len)
{
    printf("aaaaa\n");
    return dst;
}

static void * (*resolve_memcpy (void))(void *, const void *, size_t)
{
    if(use_embed == 1) {
        return memcpy;
    } else {
        return my_memcpy;
    }
}

void *memcpy2 (void *, const void *, size_t) __attribute__ ((ifunc ("resolve_memcpy")));

#define memcpy memcpy2

// extern void *memcpy (void *, const void *, size_t);

int main() {
    int source = 5;
    int dest = 6;
    memcpy(&dest, &source, sizeof(source));
    printf("%d %d\n", use_embed, dest);
    return 0;
}

==== EDIT3 ====
Seem that my question is equal to the following question for now:

Is there any ways that I can import memcpy from c library to somewhere with some name memcpy_origin, and refine a memcpy which is not a macro, and make it actually calls memcpy_origin or some self-defined my_memcpy?
Or, Is there any ways that I can decide whether to import memcpy from c library, or define a memcpy of myself? This should be done when loading dynamic libraries in runtime.


I'm inclined to suspect that the issue is related to the second ASIMD line, which expands to a declaration that seems to apply a hidden attribute to the symbol memcpy (and also defines an alias for it).  Why do you need this?  It seems at best redundant with ifunc.  What happens if you remove that line, and instead add the ifunc attribute to memcpy, and have your resolver function just return __tiflash_memcpyin those cases where that is appropriate?  This is more along the lines of the example in GCC's documentation forifunc`.

See GNU's docs for ifunc.  These should apply to Clang as well, inasmuch as Clang's support for function attributes is an exercise in mimicking GCC.

Also, names that begin with double underscores are reserved identifiers: "All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use."  If you can't figure out what's going on, the first thing to do is remove all sources of undefined behavior.

@JohnBollinger do you mean extern typeof(memcpy) memcpy __attribute__((ifunc(STRINGIFY(tiflash_memcpy_resolver)))); ?

@calvin, basically yes.  Do see the example in the docs I linked.  Though I'm not seeing why you would write STRINGIFY(tiflash_memcpy_resolver) when you could just write "tiflash_memcpy_resolver" (given that tiflash_memcpy_resolver seems to be a literal, not a macro name).

@JohnBollinger I updated my question, I rewrite the code according to the manpage of ifunc. I expect that code prints aaaaa, however, it doesn't.

@calvin, you may also need to ensure that Clang does not replace your memcpy call altogether with optimized code.  With GCC 8, for example, I need to include -fno-builtin-memcpy among the compiler flags to get a dispatch to your my_memcpy function.

What if I want to dispatch between my_memcpy and the memcpy in stdio.h?  Seems calling memcpy will cause infinite loop @JohnBollinger

Is that an observation or a prediction, @calvin?  If you haven't tried then you should do so first.  If you do get a dispatch loop then that might be a good subject for a different question.

I have updated my question, it is in EDIT2 and EDIT3. @JohnBollinger

Re EDIT3: This is called “interposition.” Search Stack Overflow and the web for “interposition”, “interpose”, and “interposing”.

See this question and this one.
